# JAXB - change property name without changing variable name in class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

So I have code like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"name", "secondName"})
public class Person {
   private String name;
   private String secondName;

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
      this.secondName = secondName;
   }

   public String getSecondName() {
      return secondName;
   }
}
```

And when I want to create XML file it makes me:

```
<person>
   <name>John</name>
   <secondName>Smith</secondName>
</person>
```

Is it any way to make in xml file `<second-name>` instead of `<secondName>` without changing in class on `private String second-name`?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I should just do this:

```
@XmlElement(name="second-name")
public String getSecondName() {
   return secondName;
}
```